# update a table on pandas by id

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, streamlit

Hi I have a code connected to DB (SQLite)
this is the data frame that shows on the web app

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s8cP.png)

as you can see, in row 9 there is no value in the result column
what I want to happen is that a user can update a specific result by row id

this is a snippet of the code:

```
if selected == 'Editor':
        project_names = st.selectbox('Select Project:', ['Lightspeed', 'Quantom'])

        if project_names == 'Lightspeed':
            con = sqlite3.connect('Performance.db')
            c = con.cursor()
            c.execute('''
                                      SELECT
                                      *
                                      FROM Results
                                      ''')

            # machines_option = ('Select Machine', ('QLS250', 'QLS450', 'QLS650', 'QLS800'))
            tdf = pd.DataFrame(c.fetchall(), columns=['Name', 'Test', 'Machine', 'SmartNics', 'Result'])
```

what I want to do exactly is that a user can choose a row and update a column in that row

Is that possible?

p.s: if any information is missing please let me know

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is possible study the sqlite update statement at https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-update/.

- Create a streamlit widget like number input for the user to input the ID to modify. Call it var1.
- Create a number input widget for the result. Call it var2
- Create a button, once the user has completed the input, update sqlite db with the following statement when the button is pressed.

```
UPDATE Results
SET Result = var2
WHERE ID = var1;
```

Results is the table name.

#### Sample code

You can add data and update data by id.

```
import streamlit as st 
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd


conn = sqlite3.connect('performance.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def create_result_table():
    c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Results(ID integer PRIMARY KEY, Name TEXT, Result integer)')

def add_result(name, result):
    c.execute('INSERT INTO Results(name, result) VALUES (?,?)', (name, result))
    conn.commit()

def update_result(id, result):
    c.execute('UPDATE Results SET result=? WHERE ID=?', (result, id))
    conn.commit()


create_result_table()

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from Results", conn)
st.table(df)

st.subheader('Add')
with st.form(key='add', clear_on_submit=True):
    name = st.text_input(label='Enter name')
    result = st.number_input(label='Enter result value', min_value=0)
    if st.form_submit_button(label='Add'):
        add_result(name, result)

st.subheader('Update')
with st.form(key='update', clear_on_submit=True):
    idnum = st.number_input(label='Enter id to update', min_value=0)
    result = st.number_input(label='Enter result value', min_value=0)
    if st.form_submit_button(label='Update'):
        update_result(idnum, result)

st.subheader('Updated table')
df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from Results", conn)
st.table(df)

conn.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response
this is what I did:
            if project_names == 'Lightspeed':
                con = sqlite3.connect('Performance.db')
                c = con.cursor()

                var1 = st.number_input('Enter Row:')
                var2 = st.number_input('Enter Updated Result:')
                if st.button("Submit"):
                    insertSQL =  f"""UPDATE Results
                    SET Result = var2
                    WHERE ID = var1;
                        """

                    crud(insertSQL, 'Performance.db')

Comment: and this is what i got on the web app

  OperationalError: no such column: var2

Comment: Use {var2} and {var1}

Comment: it worked!!! thank you! but not i have something else that I didn't have before:StreamlitAPIException: ("Expected bytes, got a 'int' object", 'Conversion failed for column Result with type object')

Comment: Your database example under Result column has a comma in the number. So perhaps this is not an integer but a string. Check the schema of your sqlite db. Notice your var2 is an integer. Try to use var2 = st.text_input().

Comment: in my SQLite db it shows: Result    INTEGER
i tried to change it to st.text_input() but it still shows the same error

Comment: What is function crud()

Comment: def crud(sqlString, path):
    db = sqlite3.connect('Performance.db')
    c = db.cursor()
    c.execute(sqlString)
    db.commit()
    db.close()

Comment: I added a sample code in my answer with ability to add and update data.